# Unexpected First Page in Latex Document

Tags: page

I am writing my thesis using a university provided Latex template. I am getting a super weird first page at the very beginning of the 100 Page document. It seems to be a compressed form of the "symbols" chapter without new lines. I have not figured out why this page is created. Can you guys tell me where I have to look for the problem?

[image: unexpected first page]

Here are my usepackages:

```
\usepackage[nenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{csquotes}    %\enquote{text}FuerAnfuehrungszeichen
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand*\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\usepackage[headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} %[plainheadsepline]
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage[squaren]{siunitx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{listofsymbols}
\lstset{breaklines=true,frame=single, language=Python, numbers=left,title=\lstname, basicstyle=\tiny    }

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
```

And my settings:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\SIunits[derived]

\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\clearscrheadings
\ihead[\headmark] {\headmark}
\ohead[\pagemark] {\pagemark}
%renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{\ihead[\headmark]{\headmark}, \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}}
\cfoot[] {}
\automark[section]{chapter}
%\automark[subsection]{section}
%\chead[]{}
```

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately the information is not sufficient to even make a guess. Probably unrelated, but `nenglish` is not a `babel` option.

Comment: We really need to see a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates and reproduces your problem.  That probably includes (but isn't necessarily limited to) your usage of `listofsymbols` package macros.

Comment: as it is the first page you should be able to show a _complete_ test document

Comment: If you look at the list of the errors, you'll see one of them is  "Undefined control sequence," which is complaining about `\SIunits`. Because this is undefined, the optional parameter `[derived]` is just printed out and that's what's creating the page. When you get unexpected output, the first thing to do is fix all the errors that are being reported.

Comment: BTW: Loading packages more than once is not recommended even if it works. It makes the document preamble confusing and provokes errors when making changes.

Comment: never ignore error messages, the pdf output is not intended to be usable if you scroll past an error. `! Package babel Error: Unknown option 'nenglish'. Either you misspelled it`  and `! LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'squaren' for package siunitx.`

Comment: fixed it by avoiding by avoiding any sort of symbols package. My symbols are now listed in a tabular. Thank you guys!